# Trying to improve WPF application startup performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, startup

> Update
>
> I have updated with the code sample running with at application
>   startup, and uploaded a new image of performance profile results. I do
>   not understand the reason that there is no activity in the 1st second.
>   That seems to be the most significant delay, and I want to understand
>   if this is the WPF or dot net framework doing something?
>
> End Update

In the UI thread utilization graph I can see beforethe disk IO (blue line) there is again mostly blank + app code (green). How can I find out what is happening in the blank area.

The other thing I have seen is that XAML is being parsed while app loading (blue area). The xaml is present in a different project and is being referenced here. I was wondering if there is any way to pre-parse the xaml since it is in a different project.

I understand the question is a bit too broad, but suggestions on how to proceed or pointers to the right tool (preferably free) will be valuable.

[image]

My App.XAML only contains:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        new Entry().Show();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

And the XAML of Entry is

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="Some.Namespace.Entry"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Some.Namespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Header ="Header" Width="1700" Height="900"
        telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">

</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Code behind for this:

```
public Entry()
        {
            RadWindowInteropHelper.SetAllowTransparency(this, false);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

> UPDATE
>   TcpView did not reveal any network traffic (I did not expect this). Switching off malware may not be feasible. I did try to get another report using Jet Brains profiler, this shows that almost a second of time is spent in verifying access, is this reasonable, tried to find more online but not getting any results.

[image]

Comment: It is usually the jitter or the disk that cause startup delays.  But you have good evidence that this is not the case here, it is external code that is not part of the process and therefore can't be seen by the diagnostic tools that caused this delay.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  Next use TcpView to see what kind of network traffic is a triggered by the startup.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks, I will try the TcpView for network traffic tomorrow. Not really sure getting anti-malware temporarily disabled will be easy (considering the approval required). Also is there a way by which the xaml could be parsed ahead of time (blue part), also wondering about the green part.... I have practically no code, so it is from third party controls? Might try and ngen it, not sure what benefits I will see.

Answer (score 1):

There are several general techniques that may help you decrease your WPF application startup time:

- Generate native images using Ngen.exe
- Use MultiCore JIT if Ngen is not applicable
- Use ReadyToRun in conjunction with MultiCore JIT for .NET Core (.NET 6/7) projects, since there is no Ngen for them
- Load Data on Demand. I think is is not your case, but may be useful for the full picture. For example, DevExpress has [Virtual Source](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/10803/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/bind-to-data/bind-to-any-data-source-with-virtual-sources) and [Server Mode](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/116265/controls-and-libraries/data-editors/common-features/binding-to-data/server-mode) features to do this asynchronously for you.
- You can also wrap "heavy" views in in controls that delay their loading without freezing the UI. For example, you can use [DevExpress LoadingDecorator](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Core.LoadingDecorator)
- Make sure that your view controls are not expanded of outside the visible area. For example, if you have StackPanel with ListBox inside, ListBox will create all its elements at once, because StackPanel doesn't limit height for its children, and they "think" that they have infinite height. As a result, ListBox will create all visual elements at once and significantly decrease your performance.
- As simple way to determine bottlenecks, you can comment UI, you can comment our XAML parts and see how this affects startup

Here is a blog post that might be helpful: [9 Tips to Reduce WPF App Startup Time](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2023/01/26/9-tips-to-reduce-wpf-app-startup-time.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Have you run the app in Release mode? That alone might improve the startup time.

A crude thing I've done in the past is to start the app with debugging, and continuously hit break in Visual Studio. If the debugger always stops at the same spot, that's the problem area. Hopefully, it's in your own code so you have the ability to change it.

If you have access to a profiler that instruments your code, try using that. Visual Studio comes with one, but you can only use it with certain licenses.

Comment: Yes, have run it in release mode and tried to ngen the images as well. I am using the VS profiler (the screen shot is from the report)